# OnClick action doesn't work at once but only for the first load. Live example included.

Tags: javascript

I have make a hide/show button for my site's header, but I have this "issue". If user load my site for first time, or after refresh, this button needs to click two times for work. But only for the first time. Then it works normally! Any idea why is this happening?

Live example at the comment below. Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The js code is:

```
function display_news(){
var sheader_1 = document.getElementById("sheader_a");
var sheader_2 = document.getElementById("sheader_b");
if (sheader_1.style.display == 'block')
     sheader_1.style.display  = 'none', 
     sheader_2.style.display  = 'block';
else  sheader_1.style.display  = 'block', 
     sheader_2.style.display  = 'none';
     ;}
```

if you alert the value of sheader_1 the first time you load the page, result is an empty string, so your code won't do anything (it will jump to the else statement).

One way to make it work would be:

```
function display_news(){
var sheader_1 = document.getElementById("sheader_a");
var sheader_2 = document.getElementById("sheader_b");
//here we also check if display property is empty
if (sheader_1.style.display == 'block' || sheader_1.style.display == '') 
     sheader_1.style.display  = 'none', 
     sheader_2.style.display  = 'block';
else  sheader_1.style.display  = 'block', 
     sheader_2.style.display  = 'none';
     ;}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Th0rndike!!! Your correction was OK but Pranav corrects syntax too!!! :)

Comment: I find it unfair that he got the right answer since he answered 5 minutes later than me and his answer is exactly the same as mine.

Comment: I am really sorry my friend!!! You are right... I test your example again and it works!!! It was my fault when I did paste your code. I want to be fair, so your question will be the accepted because it was faster as you said and correct after all!!! Sorry again...

Comment: Thanks for the correction. @Pranav sorry my friend, but I just can't shut my mouth when i find something unfair.

Comment: @Th0rndike:- it is okay that you gave the answer first when i was drafting my answer ..I have no hard  feeling for you, we are here for learn and help ..so i am fine buddy whether he accepts my answer or yours..

Comment: and +1 from my side too :):)

Answer (score 2):

```
 function display_header(){
 var sheader_1 = document.getElementById("sheader_a");
 var sheader_2 = document.getElementById("sheader_b");

   if (sheader_1.style.display == 'block' || sheader_1.style.display=='')
      {
         sheader_1.style.display  = 'none';
           sheader_2.style.display  = 'block';
      }
   else  {
     sheader_1.style.display  = 'block'; 
     sheader_2.style.display  = 'none';
        }
     }
```

[WORKING FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zbdN5/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.getComputedStyle(sheader_1).display
```

You need to get the computed style of the element. Else this conditional `if (sheader_1.style.display == 'block')` won't work because display will be empty.

In Internet Explorer the method for computed style is: `element.currentStyle`.

I suggest using jQuery in this case.

Answer (score 1):

When the page loads, sheader_1's display is not block, but an empty string.

You can therefore change your condition to:

```
if (sheader_1.style.display != 'none')
```